# How can I mock axios API calls? with using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, jestjs, axios

Hi I'm testing my vuex action async function which is calling api via axios, but I have some problem that it show error like  this "
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property `data` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

```
  35 |     commit('storeSearchValue', name);
  36 |     const url = process.env.VUE_APP_URL_API_News + '/news' + '?q=' + name;
> 37 |     const { data } = await axios.get(url);"
```

my vue js code is

```
 async updateSearchValue({ commit }, name) {
    commit('storeSearchValue', name);
    const url = process.env.VUE_APP_URL_API_News + '/news' + '?q=' + name;
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    commit('storeNewsData', data.result);
  },
```

and this is test file,

```
import actions from '@/store/modules/data/data-actions.js'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  createLocalVue
} from '@vue/test-utils';
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueRouter);
jest.mock('axios');

describe('', () => {
  test('updateSearchValue', async () => {
    const commit = jest.fn()
    const name = jest.fn()

    await actions.updateSearchValue({
      commit,
      name
    })

    expect(commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('updateSearchValue', name)
  })

})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used `jest.mock('axios')` which is automatically generating mock for module and it will create `jest.fn()` for `axios.get`, but it will return `undefined` unless you tell it otherwise

Since you're expecting it to return a resolved promise with object with `data` property you can use:

```
axios.get.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({
  data: 'mock data'
});
```

or the short-hand:

```
axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: 'mock data' });
```

#### Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60433603/637367)

Comment: but it keeps show me the error like this  TypeError: _axios.default.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function..

Comment: @Erika probably because you have removed `jest.mock('axios');`

Answer (score 8):

I'm working with jest and TS and trying to do:

```
axios.get.mockReturnValue...
```

or:

```
axios.get.mockImplementationOnce...
```

returned the following error:

```
TypeError: mockedAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce is not a function
```

The thing that finally did the trick for me was:

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

axios.get = jest.fn()
            .mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'mock data' }));
```